# How can I realistically secure the AWS service account that Terraform uses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm looking for a way to secure the AWS service account, which is a Programmatic access user account which Terraform uses. I can think of utilizing a policy that abides by Principle of least privilege, which helps, but I am looking to take this further.

Would enabling MFA or SSO cause the service account to be inaccessible when running a `Terraform Apply`? I plan on having the service account credentials exist within Terraform Cloud as secrets.

Comment: Realistically, this is next to impossible unless you want to constantly modify the policy as you add new services.

Comment: 1) secrets of service accounts could be rotated often 2) [terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) offers you a better way of segregating environments limiting the blast radius.
Just to say this is not the problem of `aws` provider alone but the whole `terraform` problem

Comment: MFA can be good. For that you can have IAM role which you assume prior deployment. The IAM role would require MFA code.

Comment: "I plan on having the service account credentials exist within Terraform Cloud as secrets." that would probably be the biggest issue I see in the question that you would want to improve.